LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 Forbidden Error in Strapi Custom Plugin During Access Token Exchange
I'm currently working on a custom plugin in Strapi that integrates LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 for user authentication.
The flow works fine up to the point where the user is redirected back to my Strapi app with the authorization code. However, when I try to exchange this code for an access token, I consistently receive a "forbidden" error.
Here's the code what I tried:
module.exports = {
  async callback(ctx) {
    try {
      const { code } = ctx.query;
      
      const tokenResponse = await fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          code,
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:1337/api/connect/linkedin/callback',
          client_id: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
      });

      const { access_token } = await tokenResponse.json();

      const userResponse = await fetch('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
      });

      const userData = await userResponse.json();
      
      ctx.send(userData);

    } catch (err) {
      ctx.send({ error: err.message }, 500);
    }
  },
};


I confirmed that the client ID and client secret are correct and properly set in the environment variables. I verified that the redirect_uri is the same as the one configured in LinkedIn's developer portal. I ensured that the LinkedIn app has the necessary scopes (openid, profile, email).
When I manually use Postman to make the request with the same parameters, I get the correct access token and can successfully retrieve user information from LinkedIn's /userinfo endpoint.
Issue: Despite these checks, the code fails at the access token exchange step with a "forbidden" error.
What I used:
Strapi version: 4.25.7 and
Node.js version: v20.15.1 and
LinkedIn API: OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect

This code was worked for me
  async getLinkedinProfile(ctx, next) {
    const {accessToken} = ctx.query;
    if (!accessToken) {
      ctx.response.status = 400;
      ctx.response.body = { message: "Access token is required" };
      return;
    }
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
    
    const linkedinProfile = response.data;
    const pluginStore = await strapi.store({ type: 'plugin', name: 'users-permissions' });
    const settings = await pluginStore.get({ key: 'advanced' });
    let userPermissionEntry = await strapi.db.query("plugin::users-permissions.user").findOne({
      where: { email: linkedinProfile?.email },
    });
    if (!userPermissionEntry) {
      const role = await strapi
      .query('plugin::users-permissions.role')
      .findOne({ where: { type: settings.default_role } });
      userPermissionEntry = await strapi.entityService.create('plugin::users-permissions.user', {
        data: {
          username: linkedinProfile.name,
          email: linkedinProfile.email, // If LinkedIn API provides email address
          provider: 'linkedin',
          confirmed: true, // Or false if you want the user to confirm email
          blocked: false,
          role: {
            connect : [role.id.toString()],
          },
        },
      });
    }
    const token = strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].service('jwt').issue({ id: userPermissionEntry.id })
    
    const responseBody = {
        jwt: token,
        user: {
          id: userPermissionEntry.id,
          username: userPermissionEntry.username,
          email: userPermissionEntry.email,
          provider: userPermissionEntry.provider,
          confirmed: userPermissionEntry.confirmed,
          blocked: userPermissionEntry.blocked,
          created_at: userPermissionEntry.createdAt,
          updated_at: userPermissionEntry.updatedAt,
          is_first_login: userPermissionEntry.isFirstLogin,
        }
      };
    ctx.response.status = 200;
    ctx.response.body = responseBody;
  },


Thanks for your answer Mr. Kalpesh. It is really helpful. Thanks a lot.
